# Reducing shuffle disk usage in Spark aggregations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in hive which is 100 GB of size. I am trying to group, count function and storing the result as hive table..my hard disk has 600 GB of space, by the time job reaches to 70% all of the disk space is being occupied.

so my job got fails...How can I minimize the shuffle data writes

```
hiveCtx.sql("select * from gm.final_orc")
  .repartition(300)
  .groupBy('col1, 'col2).count
  .orderBy('count desc)
  .write.saveAsTable("gm.result")
```

[spark_memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPUoO.png)

Comment: I am trying to get the count of group by(col1,col2)..I have tested on small data set ..it is giving output as expected..but while i put my complete data set it going OOM in disk due to shuffle data

Comment: Ok, I simplified the code in the question. You can use symbols to refer to simple columns. `groupBy` performs a projection so you don't need the separate `select` and `count` exists as a transformation.

Comment: Where do you run out of disk space: during `repartition` or during the `groupBy` shuffle?

Comment: at the time of group by

Comment: Then my answer is focused on the right problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cloud-based execution environments adding more disk is usually a very easy and cheap option. If your environment does not allow this and you've verified that your [shuffles settings](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#shuffle-behavior) are reasonable, e.g., compression (on by default) is not changed, then there is only one solution: implement your own staged map-reduce using the fact that counts can be re-aggregated via `sum`.

1. Partition your data in any way that seems fit (by date, by directory, by number of files, etc.)
2. Perform the counting by `col1` and `col2` as separate Spark actions.
3. Re-group and re-aggregate.
4. Sort.

For simplicity, let's assume that `col1` is an integer. Here is how I'd break up processing into 8 separate jobs, re-aggregating their output. If `col1` is not an integer, you can hash it or you can use another column.

```scala
def splitTableName(i: Int) = s"tmp.gm.result.part-$i"

// Source data
val df = hiveCtx.sql("select col1, col2 from gm.final_orc")

// Number of splits
val splits = 8

// Materialize partial aggregations
val tables = for {
  i <- 0 until splits
  tableName = splitTableName(i)
  // If col1 % splits will create very skewed data, hash it first, e.g.,
  // hash(col1) % splits. hash() uses Murmur3.
  _ = df.filter('col1 % splits === i)
    // repartition only if you need to, e.g., massive partitions are causing OOM
    // better to increase the number of splits and/or hash to un-skew skewed data
    .groupBy('col1, 'col2).count
    .write.saveAsTable(tableName)
} yield hiveCtx.table(tableName)

// Final aggregation
tables.reduce(_ union _)
  .groupBy('col1, 'col2)
  .agg(sum('count).as("count"))
  .orderBy('count.desc)
  .write.saveAsTable("gm.result")

// Cleanup temporary tables
(0 until splits).foreach { i =>
  hiveCtx.sql(s"drop table ${splitTableName(i)}")
}
```

If `col1` and `col2` are so diverse and/or so large that the partial aggregation storage is causing disk space issues then you have to consider one of the following:

- Smaller number of splits will generally use less disk space.
- Sorting on `col1` will help (because of Parquet run length encoding) but that would slow down execution.
- How to create splits that are independent, e.g., find distinct values of `col1`, partition those into groups.

If you are extremely short on disk space you'd have to implement multi-step re-aggregation. The simplest approach is to generate the splits one at a time and keep a running aggregate. The execution would be much slower but it will use a lot less disk space.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Sim..In my case both col1 and col2 are integers..I will try this code and update you with result..

Comment: .agg(sum('count).as("count"))..........in this step from which library you imported "sum" function

Comment: I added a comment to the code about how to use hashing to reduce data skew in the splits. Did this work out for you?

Comment: Thanks Sim,the split worked and there is no much shuffle data write..I have attached the snap for the same.But for the order by of each stage it took long time to complete..is their a way we can reduce sorting time

Comment: When you use `orderBy()`, which gives you a total ordering, you are pushing all the data through a single worker. Since your problem seems to require a total ordering, there is no simple way around this. In the case of huge data sets, it may make sense to implement partial sorting and then custom merge aggregation but that's a lot of tricky custom code to write.